# HTML text input length increases automatically in my JSP

Tags: html, jsp, struts

```
<tr class="searchrow1">
             <td class="createcolumn1" >
                            <font class="texto1"><bean:message key="booktypForm.booktypDesc"/>:</font>
                    </td>
                    <td class="createcolumn2" >

                            <html:textarea property='restypDesc'  style="width:189%"  readonly='<%= viewflag %>' tabindex='3' accesskey='k'  onfocus="highlight(event)"  onchange="validateField(restypDesc,'numstr','chk',1,100,'imgbooktypDesc',0);"/>
                            <c:set var="errorMsg" value="${requestScope.restypDesc}"/>
                            <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${not empty errorMsg}">
                                 <img  id="imgbooktypDesc"   src="<c:url value='/images/tooltip/error.png'/>" width='19.5' height='19.5' align='top' border='0' onMouseover="ddrivetip('<html:errors property="booktypDesc"></html:errors>','<bean:message key="tooltip.server.size"/>','<bean:message key="tooltip.server.color"/>')" onMouseout="hideddrivetip()" >
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                 <img  id="imgbooktypDesc"  style="visibility:hidden" src="<c:url value='/images/tooltip/error.png'/>" width='19.5' height='19.5' align='top' border='0' onMouseover="ddrivetip(message,'<bean:message key="tooltip.client.size"/>','<bean:message key="tooltip.client.color"/>');" onMouseout="hideddrivetip()" >
                            </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>                                
                    </td>
                  </tr>
```

As you can see from the above snippet, this is a text box in a JSP. This text box is used to fill the description and is ultimately stored in the database. However the maximum length of the database field is 100 words. I validate this restriction through Javascript, but currently if I enter more than 100 words then the width of the text box is increased automatically. Any help?

Thanks[image]

Comment: You have `style="width:189%"` that is a likely culprit.

Comment: That's impossibly a JSP problem. Your problem is in the CSS. Please edit your question to show the JSP-generated HTML/CSS output instead of the JSP source code.

Comment: @ BAlusC , thje css we'r using is generic to every page like common.css , cant change generic css......

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting css max-width?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the length of your textbox's content in real time, you can use the `oninput` event to assess and restrict the length of the input every time it changes. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LJ3PK/